# Pass a table as variable - Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I have a url: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/ProfitAndLoss?fromDate=2019-06-01&toDate=2019-06-30 which I will use after to call Xero's API.. I need to change fromDate and toDate dynamically. I thought to use https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/ProfitAndLoss?fromDate=${start}&toDate=${end}. Then, add 'Data grid' with dates to be replaced in the string. But then, I tried to 'Set variables'/'Get variables' but I keep on getting the error 'Only 1 input row was expected to set the variables and at least 2 were received.' What am I doing wrong?

[image]
Current transformation:
[image]
Transformation:

[image]

Sub-job:

[image]

Final transformation:
[image]

Comment: Create one more **transformation** in sub job  before final **transformation 2**and use **get rows from result** and then use set variable

Comment: @PKP, can you, please, take a look at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C45A3tnzBvIIBwWTEXM11cqDLg36Adx3/view?usp=sharing? I've added as you suggested but still the only one row gets passed/

Comment: here is your file https://aws-pkp.s3.amazonaws.com/transformation.zip . I have checked a log. It seemed fine

Comment: I guess it is the specifics of the Xero step i.e. that it doesn't accept variables?!

Comment: It seems like variables are updated in Set/Get var, but then, it sends a request to Xero first without changing the var to the next value

Answer (score 1):

In  the **set variable**  you can only set **one** row. but if you want to pass multiple rows then I suggest you to use **job**. In job first transformation use **Data Grid** and then **copy rows to result**. then create one more **sub job**. For setting variable use **transformation**. Make sure  **execute at every input row is checked**.    this should be your **subjob** Structure
[image]

Comment: Just got the same transformation. Now I am not getting any error but just one row is passed. Do I need to use something like Set Var/Get Var?

Comment: Did you use **copy rows to result**? If yes, then you can get all rows in next **subjob**